# When I try to run or debug my code in Pycharm I only get errors

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

When I try to debug my "Hello World" program in python on pycharm I get following error messages and could not find any solution online yet. This problem occurs aswell when I try to run my code.

This is what the error says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)

  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
    stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable

  File "C:\Users\arz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tokenize.py", line 447, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/python'
```

I found a thread where it is advised to run pycharm as administrator but for me it changed nothing.

```
print("hello world")
```

Comment: Would like to see more on your code that is throwing this `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:/python'`
Just re-read your problem and it looks like there is only one statement in your code. Would you please check your Python installation directory, because it looks like it's in D: where the user doesn't have access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your .py name , then try reinstalling pycharm in c drive. its easy way out.